# pdfMake opens an empty tab

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, pdf-generation

I am trying to implement pdf generating into my web application so i decided to use pdfMake for this.

however, after importing everything needed...

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
(pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

my pdf generating function :

```
generatePDF() {  
let docDefinition = {  
  header: 'C#Corner PDF Header',  
  content: 'Sample PDF generated with Angular and PDFMake for C#Corner Blog'  
};  

pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
}
```

my button code :

```
<button class="botright" (click)="generatePDF()" mat-raised-button >Téléchargez le bordereau de prise en charge <mat-icon>picture_as_pdf</mat-icon></button>
```

...clicking the button i assigned to open the pdf only opens a [blank web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqvok.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the errors raised in the browser's console but if I have to guess, I'd say it's most likely caused by the wrong format of the 'content' variable, declared as an string here instead of an array :

example from [pdfmake's playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) :

```
var documentDefinition = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, 
this line will be divided into at least two lines'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every browser can behave differently to a command such as `open` Modern Browser security should consider it as a `pop-up request` thus block or blank such viral activity.

[image]

**a different effect**

[image]

**another may allow a new browsing window not a tab**

[image]